# Getting tabindex value for UIComponent

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I'd like to get `tabindex` of current `UIComponent` in generic way. `getTabIndex()` is available only for few components. Is there any way of getting it without casting component to proper type?

I was thinking about getting `tabindex` attribute for current component but how to to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`UIComponent#getAttributes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes%28%29).

```
Object tabindex = component.getAttributes().get("tabindex");
if (tabindex != null) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I use this in RENDER_RESPONSE phase and it seems that no such attribute is present in attributes map. It's normal or am I doing sth wrong?